# Python linked list- Nonetype error in recursive remove function

Tags: python

I am teaching myself Python and working through the construction of a singly linked list class. The class constructors, add, and display functions all work, but when trying to implement a recursive remove function, I find that either the list does not change at all, or it deletes itself entirely.  Adding print statements into the recursive function that are intended to print the value of the node generate Nonetype attribute errors, which suggest to me that I may have an issue with the arguments being passed in, as the object that I think is a node is apparently not.  I've reviewed the other Nonetype questions I've found on SE, but either they haven't shed the needed light or I've just misunderstood them.
Class Definitions:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.next_node = None
        
class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

Remove functions:

```
def remove(self, target):
     if(self.head == None):
          print("List is empty!")
          return None
     else:
          print(str(self.head.data))
          self.head = self.remove_target(self.head, target)
          return self.head
        
def remove_target(self, head, target):
     print("Target: " + str(target) + "Head: " + str(head.data)) #Nonetype errors occur here
     if(head == None):
          return head
     if(head.data == target):
          print("target found")
          head = head.next_node
          return head
     else:
          head.next_node = self.remove_target(head.next_node, target)
          return head
```

My previous programming experience is in c++, and I think part of the problem is that wrapper functions used to hide data members in c++ aren't really a thing in Python?  However, the same results occur when I call the recursive function directly from the test program.  Any light that can be shed would be most appreciated!

Comment: The code in the question should demonstrate at least one failure.

Comment: I added some test code around it on my own. I don't know if it's the same as yours. I changed indentation, too. I got "target found" but then you make no attempt to alter the list around the removal point. You just dump the whole list and assign the remainder after the removal point as the new head -- so it is therefore all that will remain. I'll leave this as a debugging exercise for you.

Comment: For simplicity, I'd suggest just using ONE class (`Node` in your case). That's what I've done in the past. If you want some code for that, please let me know!

Comment: Hmm.  Is pass by reference vs pass by value a relevant concept in Python?  I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around how this should work without pointers, which I understand aren't a thing here?